# Coldfusion Youtube Upload Video Binary File Data

Tags: video, coldfusion, youtube, youtube-api, coldfusion-10

I am trying to upload the video file using Api v.3 of Youtube. As is stated in the documentation, in order to upload the file it should like this

```
PUT UPLOAD_URL HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer AUTH_TOKEN
Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
Content-Type: CONTENT_TYPE

{BINARY_FILE_DATA}
```

and this is what I got.

```
<cffile action="readbinary" file="fileIuploadedtoserver" variable="objBinaryData" />
<cfhttp method="put" url="#seturl#"  multipart="yes" >
      <cfhttpparam type="header" value="Bearer #form.rectoken#" name="Authorization">
      <cfhttpparam type="header" value="#filesize#" name="Content-Length">
      <cfhttpparam type="header" value="video/*" name="Content-Type">
      <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#objBinaryData#">
    </cfhttp>
```

also tried

```
<cfhttp method="put" url="#seturl#"  multipart="yes" >
      <cfhttpparam type="header" value="Bearer #form.rectoken#" name="Authorization">
      <cfhttpparam type="header" value="#filesize#" name="Content-Length">
      <cfhttpparam type="header" value="video/*" name="Content-Type">
      <cfhttpparam type="body" value="fileReadBinary('C:\FTP\beta.3gs.org\users\admin\wwwdocs\youtubecfc\tmp\#cffile.serverfile#')">
    </cfhttp>
```

The url is the location of a previous response. All I get is a 308 response code with no content-range, upload incomplete. I tried small video files (184kb). The video is not being uploaded and I can't figure out why. Any Ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the example in the link http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0693d5dae123bcd28f6d-7ff8.html. It might help.

Comment: Why not use the FILE type for cfhttpparam?

Comment: @RaymondCamden HEY RAYMOND!!! if i use file type i get a error message about invalid request...

Comment: @GauravS This is an old example... nth works with the new API anymore...